# Searching index of element in list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've a list of list and I need to get the index of that element in it.

Suppose I've a list `[[0,0,0,'P'],[0,0,0,0],[0,'Q',0,0],[0,0,0,0]]`.

How can I get index of `'P'` and `'Q'`, if there's only one `'P'` and one `'Q'`?

I tried: `list.index('P')`,

but got `ValueError: 'P' is not in list`

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension and `enumerate` at each iteration:

```
l = [[0,0,0,'P'],[0,0,0,0],[0,'Q',0,0],[0,0,0,0]]

indexes = [[i for i, a in enumerate(b) if a == "P" or a == "Q"] for b in l]
```

You can also use a dictionary that stores the letter and a corresponding list with the sublist index and the letter index in the sublist:

```
new_dict = [{a:[i, b] for b, a in enumerate(c) if a == "P" or a == "Q"} for i, c in enumerate(l)]

new_dict = [i for i in new_dict if i]

final_dict = {**new_dict[0], **new_dict[1]}
print(final_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Q': [2, 1], 'P': [0, 3]}
```

Finally, to get the complete sublists:

```
final_values = final_dict.values()
```

Output:

```
[[2, 1], [0, 3]]
```

Comment: If you put `"P"` and `"Q"` in a set before the list comprehension, `if a == "P" or a == "Q"` could be shortened to `if a in P_Q_set`

Comment: `print(indexes)` is giving `[[3], [], [1], []]` as output, how can I format it in to `[2, 1] &  [0, 3]` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking the index at which the element is in the sublist, you can try this:

```
input_list = [[0,0,0,'P'],[0,0,0,0],[0,'Q',0,0],[0,0,0,0]]

def find_position(input_list, element):
    index = 0
    for sublist in input_list:
        if element in sublist:
            return index
        index += 1
    return None

find_position(input_list, 'P')
OUT: 0

find_position(input_list, 'Q')
OUT: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the elements of your search array are themselves arrays so you need to do some work to get what you want.

I will suppose that when searching for 'P' and 'Q' you are expecting to get a tuple as a result where the first value refers to the array where the search element appears and the second value refers to the index of the search element in the array where it appears.

You can write the following function

```
def find_position(array, elem):
    for i, arr in enumerate(array):
        if elem in arr:
            return (i, arr.index(elem))
    return (-1, -1) # elem do not exist


find_position(l, 'Q')
Out: (2, 1)

find_position(l, 'P')
Out (0, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to search in *nested* lists:

```
for nested_list in list:
    if 'P' in nested_list:
        index_of_P = nested_list.index('P')
        break
```

**The explanation:**

`index()` method raises the `ValueError` when `'P'` is not found in `nested_list`, hence the `if` test just before its use.

As you have only one `'P'`, `break` the `for` loop after the successful search.

---

**Note:**

This is a simple but not recommended usage. After learning about the *exceptions* handling you will see more appropriate solution.

Comment: If P isn't present - why not just handle the exception thrown instead? Checking it's there first means scanning the list first, then scanning it again to find the position... By catching the exception if it occurs you've proven it's not there, while if it is, your index has only scanned as far as it needs to go and you have the index. No need to do more work than necessary.

Comment: @JonClements you are definitely right but I decided to adjust my answer to the OP (supposed) level and used his prerequisite for the single existence of `'P'`.

Comment: Fair enough - although at this "level" - it's likely they'll take the advice as gospel that you to need to check for existence to avoid an "error" (it's not an error - just an Exception which aren't necessarily bad things) in case it doesn't - which... isn't doing anyone any favours really.

Comment: @JonClements thanks for your useful comment, I little edited my answer.